# Air Print Action not doing anything unless file type is png

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, printing, airprint

Wrangling with Air Print not doing anything from a button press, im trying to print a file from screen (my first time implementing this)

Ive added  the `UIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate` in .h

.m Hooked up my button which has been checked as working correctly

Button handler code:

```
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mylocalhtmlfile" ofType:@"HTML"];
NSData *dataFromPath = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

UIPrintInteractionController *printController = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];

if(printController && [UIPrintInteractionController canPrintData:dataFromPath]) {

    printController.delegate = self;

    UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
    printInfo.jobName = [path lastPathComponent];
    printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
    printController.printInfo = printInfo;
    printController.showsPageRange = YES;
    printController.printingItem = dataFromPath;

    void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) = ^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
        if (!completed && error) {
            NSLog(@"FAILED! due to error in domain %@ with error code %u", error.domain, error.code);
        }
    };

    [printController presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];

}
```

I get no action whatsoever, no presentation of the air print controls or anything unless file type is set to `png`

Comment: Put this above the if statement. 
    NSLog(@"boolean check passes? %@",printController && [UIPrintInteractionController canPrintData:dataFromPath]?@"YES":@"NO");

Comment: Done that, no difference at all?

Comment: it's not meant to fix it, it's meant to log the outcome of the boolean statement. Is it YES or NO, in your console log.

Comment: thanks fo reply, I realise that. Thing is, nothing is appearing in console log.  Been playing around with this and noticed when I change `of type` to `png` i get the printer controls displayed and I get `failed to find PDF header: %PDF' not found.` in the debug console.

Comment: OK, i cannot help with that.Although you first issue means that pathForResource:@"mylocalhtmlfile" ofType:@"HTML"] is not finding a file of that type with that name. Log the values of path, dataFromPath and printController to make sure they are all correct. Then good luck, as I cannot help past there.

Comment: Ok i will check into that, Thanks for your help